# Problema ao retornar o tamanho de um arquivo com PHP e Curl

Tags: php, libcurl

Estou tentando retornar o tamanho de um arquivo com `php` e `curl` de um host externo porém ao executar o curl o `download_content_length` vem como -1, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 2):

Fiz um exemplo simples abaixo usando o JS do jQuery.

```
 $url = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js';
 $ch = curl_init( $url );

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);

 curl_exec($ch);
 $size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);

 curl_close($ch);

 echo ($size / 1024) . ' kb';
```

*output: 93.541015625 kb*

Answer (score -1):

Ao utilizar CURL existem muitas coisas que podem dar errado, por isso recomendo que você utilize algum componente para realizar essas requisições eu utilizo o [Guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) assim você terá erros mais amigáveis